# Symfony 4 make:entity --regenerate fail with: No entities were found in the "App" namespace

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

from composer.json

```
{
    "name": "symfony/website-skeleton",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "description": "A skeleton to start a new Symfony website",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
        "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/asset": "^4.0",
        "symfony/console": "^4.0",
        "symfony/expression-language": "^4.0",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
        "symfony/form": "^4.0",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.0",
        "symfony/lts": "^4@dev",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/process": "^4.0",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "^4.0",
        "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/translation": "^4.0",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "^4.0",
        "symfony/validator": "^4.0",
        "symfony/web-link": "^4.0",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-pack": "*",
        "symfony/yaml": "^4.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/browser-kit": "^4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "^4.0",
        "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "^4.0",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.5",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^4.0",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "^4.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install --symlink --relative %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false
        }
    }
}
```

from doctrine.yaml:

```
# /config/packages/doctrine.yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: training
        connections:
            training:
                dbname:   "training"
                driver:   "pdo_mysql"
                host:     "localhost"
                port:     "3306"
                user:     "userdb"
                password: "XXXXXXXXXX"
                charset:  UTF8
                mapping_types:
                    bit: boolean
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        default_entity_manager: training
        entity_managers:
            training:
                connection: training
                auto_mapping: true
```

the command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --em=training App\Entity annotation --path=src/Entity
```

produce into `src/Entity` the `Course.php` entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Course
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="course", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="id_product_idx_1", columns={"id_product"}), @ORM\Index(name="enabled_idx_1", columns={"enabled"}), @ORM\Index(name="sort_idx_1", columns={"sort"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Course
{
    ....
```

after run into the console:

```
php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App
```

this fail with error:

> No entities were found in the "App" namespace

same for

```
php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App\Entity
```

if i try

```
php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App\Entity\Course
```

the output is

> Could not find Doctrine metadata for "App\Entity\Course". Is it mapped as an entity?

what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried "php bin/console generate:doctrine:entity App:Course"?

Comment: @richin `Command generate:doctrine:entity is not defined`

Comment: "php bin/console make:entity --regenerate" Without the App Namespace?

Comment: I've tried without the namespace but it's prompted to insert it. I've tried to insert: "empty", App, App\Entity but same error occurs

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was because I wrote:

`php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App\Entity\Course`

instead of (notice double back slashes)

`php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App\\Entity\\Course`

Comment: It worked for me but I suspect there is a proper way of naming the entity using the `config/packages/doctrine.yaml`

Answer (score 1):

Look to `config/packages/doctrine.yaml`

```
 dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
```

Thats the problem. Every .orm.yml is searching in that path.

Comment: This question will marked as low quality. Please provide more information and format.

Comment: raise an error: `Unrecognized option "dir" under "doctrine.orm" in ArrayNode.php line 311`

Comment: mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: yml
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
Have u this config rows in your doctrine.yaml? If not - try to write it, please

Answer (score 1):

i have the same error and the fix that i find is to adding repositoryClass to all of my entities:

```
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\DefaultRepository")
```

The final code is like this:

```
/**
 * Key
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="`key`")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\DefaultRepository")
 */
```

Hope it help to you

Answer (score 1):

Inside `app/config/packages/doctrine.yaml`

```
...
doctrine:

...

 orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        entity_managers:
            default:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                connection: default


                #ADD THESE LINES AND CHANGE PATH IF NEEDED
                mappings:
                    App:
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\'
```

Run `php bin/console make:entity --regenerate`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Inside your entity classes, make sure the namespace is well written like this: `namespace App\Entity`

Comment: I had a typo in my namespace (upper case in place of a lower case)

Answer (score 0):

This desc is for Symfony 6;

Symfony 6 is using attributes instead of annotation. Entities re-generated by doctrine:import command produce with annotations. Because of this "php bin/console make:entity --regenerate "App\Entity"" is not working. As the first it has to be migrated by using rector.php and then "php bin/console make:entity --regenerate "App\Entity" works ;

Rector example;

```html
declare(strict_types=1);

use Rector\Symfony\Set\SymfonySetList;
use Rector\Config\RectorConfig;
use Rector\Doctrine\Set\DoctrineSetList;
use Rector\Symfony\Set\SensiolabsSetList;
use Rector\Set\ValueObject\SetList;

return static function (RectorConfig $rectorConfig): void {
    $rectorConfig->paths([
        __DIR__ . '/src/Entity'
    ]);
    $rectorConfig->symfonyContainerXml(__DIR__ . '/var/cache/dev/App_KernelDevDebugContainer.xml');
    $rectorConfig->sets([
        SymfonySetList::SYMFONY_60,
        SymfonySetList::SYMFONY_CODE_QUALITY,
        SymfonySetList::SYMFONY_CONSTRUCTOR_INJECTION
    ]);

    $rectorConfig->sets([
        DoctrineSetList::ANNOTATIONS_TO_ATTRIBUTES,
        SymfonySetList::ANNOTATIONS_TO_ATTRIBUTES,
        //SensiolabsSetList::FRAMEWORK_EXTRA_61

    ]);


};
```